# How can I post a python list to django

Tags: python, html, list

Im setting up a website where I can get some JSON list Im getting from my PRTG,  however I made it work in console, the code will filter up sensors with DOWN Status however I have no idea how to post it on Django to make a history list of the downtime of the sensors.

I have tried to post the data with the code below but I can't even load the site, it stays loading on 127.0.0.1

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
import json
import requests
import time

def index(request):
    url = "https://site.site.com/api/table.json?content=status=down&username=user&passhash=hash&count=200000"
    starttime=time.time()
    while True:
        response = requests.get(url)
        data = response.json()
        d = data
        result_list = [d for d in data['status%3Ddown'] if d['status'] == 'Down']
        time.sleep(10.0 - ((time.time() - starttime) % 10.0))

    return print(result_list)
   #return HttpResponse(result_list) this dont work either
```

I expect to get a list and if possible can someone point my how to create a record in a DB of this results, I want to make the request every 30 seconds to my PRTG in order to make a history about this and add a timer of how long any sensor has been with the label DOWN

Comment: Is the GET request to the url giving you results?

Comment: Yes it pulls the sensors on DOWN status from my PRTG and it works on CLI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey I did this long time ago but I will share both of my solutions

The easiest way was to make a pandas dataframe and render it into html and it looks like this

```
def example_page(request):
    context = {"title" : "example"}
    url = "https://prtg.c3ntro.com/api/table.json?content=status=down&username=someuser&passhash=123&count=123"
    response = requests.get(url)
    data = response.json()
    d = data
    result_list = [d for d in data['status%3Ddown'] if d['status'] == 'Down']
    df = pd.DataFrame(result_list)
    return HttpResponse(df.to_html())
```

And the other one was to create a model and then render it on my template using django_tables2 which was the best thing I could do, however previous answer is enough to share since creating a model won't answer current question. Thanks for everyone's time